# Why were only some Chimera Ants born with immense nen?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

During the Chimera Ant arc, why were the queen's elite royal guard members born with immense nen, but all of the lower-ranking Chimera Ants had to get hit by a nen user to get the ability? Especially because the queen herself doesn't have nen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it was the same reason as to why the ants started to look like different animals: Because the queen consumed said animals beforehand. The guards and Meruem were conceived *after* the queen had consumed hunters who could use nen, which were Ponzu and Pokkle. The other lower ranked ants had to learn it the way gon and killua did, as they were born before, out of normal humans who couldn't use nen.

Comment: Thanks a bunch I really appreciate the help